# Using UUID for Primary Key using Room with Android

Tags: android, android-room

I need to sync my Android mobile app with a multi-tenant database in the cloud. I thought the best way to do this was using a UUID for the Primary Key of my tables. I just started using Room and was wondering where/how I might do this and was looking for 1) opinions on using UUID as a PK with Room and 2) where I would implement this (in the model initializing the id column as this is the only way to use @NonNull)?

**UPDATE**

I used INTs but am not convinced it was the right approach. I saw an [example](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/BasicRxJavaSample) from the android developer site which showed a uuid being used. Certainly would help my cloud syncing routine, but at the expense of speed and space. I was thinking of a hybrid approach where INTs were used for PKs but UUIDs as an additional field. This way I would not have to replicate each UUID for FKs. I did some modeling and it looks like the hybrid approach would be 50% of the size of the full UUID approach (the INT only would be 25% as big).

Has anybody struggled with this same issue? Did you choose a direction (UUID, INT, or hybrid) and did you regret it or did it work well?

Comment: A UUID should generally be acceptable for use as a primary key.  But, why do you want to use a UUID versus something simpler (and smaller), such as an auto increment number?

Comment: When I synchronize the data back into the cloud in a multi-tenant database, it would ensure there are no collisions. So if we had a Project table on the phone, and a Project table in the cloud the IDs would never be similar to another persons Project table PK. If I used int for PK on the local device I would need a different PK in the cloud. I was thinking if there was a UUID as PK locally, it would make it so easy. I wouldn't have to worry about the multi-tenant environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit 2024:**

First, think of UUID as a 16-byte id, and Java 'int' as 4-byte id, Java 'long' as 8-byte id.

Advantages: Server and client can independently generate non-conflicting IDs.

Disadvantages: 1. It takes up more space. 2. Unordered, requiring other attributes to sort records.

**Old Answer:**

1. There was several reasons you have to use UUID instead of int as primary key. For example, your application is a distributed application like many people use many devices to edit one documente and you will log everyones' edit log for the version control feature. If your application is centralized(most cases), it is better to use int, or request the primary key(can be int, long or whatever) from the server. If you have to use UUID, then use it. Otherwise the int or long is a better choice.
2. At the end I will attach an example of using UUID as the primary key with android Room.
3. UUID storage space and computing speed should not be the primary consideration, unless you have encountered these problems (no need to over-optimize). For example: the storage space of a picture may be about 1MB, <del>the UUID is saved in the database in the form of String, in utf-8 format, up to 144 Byte (int is 4 Byte), which is about 1/7000 of a picture .</del> Room now uses a byte array to save uuid, using only 16 bytes(edit:2024). On the server side, UUID is not recommended as the primary key, because the server serves tens of thousands of users at the same time, and there are many queries at the same time. Although the mobile phone CPU is far weaker than the server CPU, it only serves one user at a time. Again, in scenarios where UUID has to be used, there is no need to consider optimization issues in advance.

Book.class

```
@Entity(tableName = "books")
public class Book{
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
private UUID id;
private String title;
private Date date;

public Book() {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
    date = new Date();
}

public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

}
```

AppDatabase.class

```
//*Note* use room default UUIDConverter instead after Version '2.4.0-alpha05'
@Database(entities = {Book.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({UUIDConverter.class, DateConverter.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookDatabase";

    public abstract BookDao bookDao();

    public static void init(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME).build();
        }
    }

    public static AppDatabase getINSTANCE() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) throw new IllegalStateException("init in MyApplication.class");
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

**Converters:** converters convert uuid or other format that sqlite do not support to a support type.
Edit: From [Version 2.4.0-alpha05](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.4.0-alpha05) default converter for UUID exists which is using byte array instead of String. Linking [change](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1812173/9/room/room-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/room/util/UUIDUtil.java) which can be handy for migration.

```
public class UUIDConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromUUID(UUID uuid) {
        return uuid.toString();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static UUID uuidFromString(String string) {
        return UUID.fromString(string);
    }
}

public class DateConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static long timestampFromDate(Date date) {
        return date.getTime();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date dateFromTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        return new Date(timestamp);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. Using INT really becomes a challenge with foreign key references. It ends up being a lot of lookups to sync without using a UUID. This code is very helpful and clear. Thank you. Have you used this in production environments?

Comment: What happens when you in android studio when you want to get back the id? Normally on an insert in Android you get the rowid back. How do you get the uuid back on insert?

Comment: I am very glad that my answer is helpful to you. Of course we use UUID in the production environment. Our application uses UUID in many places, such as the identifier of some downloaded resources. In my opinion, some places in our project even abuse UUID a bit. For example, in many places auto increment int is better, we still use UUID instead. I am mainly responsible for the work of the Android client, at least so far no performance problems caused by UUID have been found. The server side is not my responsibility, but I have not heard of obvious performance problems caused by UUID .@lcj

Comment: Auto increment int is create by sqlite and return to your code. UUID is create by you, and save to sqlite. You already know it before save it to database. Or it create by the server side. Then you will create a web API to get the UUIDs to client, then save it to sqlite.For example get the latest 10 books upload this week from server. The server return 10 simple data include 10 UUIDs and book summarys. Then you can get every book's detail data from server use the UUID. Hope this help you. @lcj

Comment: I started with integers and stayed with them because I was concerned about foreign keys and the proliferation of UUIDs to support them. I happen to have a lot of FKs in the database. I really don't know if it's the right call but from the server side it seemed clear GUIDs were not a good approach. FKs aside people seemed to have challenges with performance and page sizes. I do use GUIDs on some tables to uniquely identify a record but not as the PK. The downside of this approach is a lot of lookups to ensure I have the right record, which I really don't like, but....

Answer (score -3):

UUID is more hard and lower efficiency than using alias of the rowid. You just need to say column by using `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and column is alias of rowid.

When value not given then SQLite makes a integer value. Value can be up to 9223372036854775807 (you can also use negative so 2 times can happen).

Using rowid can be up to 2 times faster.

You can assign a value, it must be an integer.

Issue is uniqiueness in the cloud. If App not assign value then no problem.

If you wanted randomness then SQlite will make a unique random value if not autogenerate is used (just @PrimaryKey with Long not long in Entity) and rowid 9223372036854775807 is used (when reached SQLite finds random value).

If positive and negative randomness wanted then as well as add row with 9223372036854775807 add a negative value.

This is how you make it simply in Room

Entity like

```
@Entity
public class RandomId {

    @PrimaryKey
    Long randomId;
    String name;

    public RandomId(){}

    public Long getRandomId() {
        return randomId;
    }

    public void setRandomId(Long randomId) {
        this.randomId = randomId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Dao Like

```
@Dao
public interface RandomIdDao {

    @Insert
    long insert(RandomId randomId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM randomid ORDER BY name")
    List<RandomId> getAll();
}

@Database(version = 1,entities = {RandomId.class})
public abstract class RandomIdDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    abstract RandomIdDao randomIdDao();
}
```

Activity like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RandomIdDatabase randomIdDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        randomIdDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(this,RandomIdDatabase.class,"randomiddb")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onCreate(db);
                        /* SETUP FOR positive and negative randomids */
                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put("randomId",9223372036854775807L);
                        db.insert("RandomID", OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE,cv);
                        cv.clear();
                        cv.put("RandomId",-9223372036854775808L);
                        db.insert("RandomID", OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE,cv);
                    }
                })
                .build();
        randomIdDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().beginTransaction();
        RandomId r = new RandomId();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            r.setRandomId(null);
            r.setName("name" + String.valueOf(i));
            randomIdDatabase.randomIdDao().insert(r);
        }
        randomIdDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful();
        randomIdDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().endTransaction();
        List<RandomId> randomIds = randomIdDatabase.randomIdDao().getAll();
        for (RandomId randomId : randomIds) {
            Log.d("IDDATA","name is " + randomId.getName() + " ID is " + randomId.getRandomId());
        }
    }
}
```

Runs like

> ```
> D/IDDATA: name is null ID is -9223372036854775808
> D/IDDATA: name is null ID is 9223372036854775807
> D/IDDATA: name is name0 ID is 4107292993476813590
> D/IDDATA: name is name1 ID is 22838362508669948
> D/IDDATA: name is name10 ID is 3903077096050951194
> D/IDDATA: name is name100 ID is 948211817704090341
> D/IDDATA: name is name101 ID is 806075887185875254
> D/IDDATA: name is name102 ID is 3204631877439831564
> D/IDDATA: name is name103 ID is 1003770814770374644
> D/IDDATA: name is name104 ID is 4116052162843098839
> D/IDDATA: name is name105 ID is 3379736427023998848
> D/IDDATA: name is name106 ID is 3597159533635558763
> D/IDDATA: name is name107 ID is 3199952401843656135
> D/IDDATA: name is name108 ID is 474496762820166420
> D/IDDATA: name is name109 ID is 486041123921960369
> D/IDDATA: name is name11 ID is 1162315037045732434
> D/IDDATA: name is name110 ID is 2807178719405346105
> D/IDDATA: name is name111 ID is 3643686187723794393
> D/IDDATA: name is name112 ID is 4551641574908625814
> D/IDDATA: name is name113 ID is 482870610003853013
> D/IDDATA: name is name114 ID is 3865465837800377065
> D/IDDATA: name is name115 ID is 2934767897308599664
> D/IDDATA: name is name116 ID is 4473965121303816092
> D/IDDATA: name is name117 ID is 2244323676217441072
> D/IDDATA: name is name118 ID is 911318293674111436
> D/IDDATA: name is name119 ID is 1434915280093930897
> D/IDDATA: name is name12 ID is 2661856341619735016
> ........
> ```

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. I had not thought of this. I am still concerned about collisions, particularly in a multi-tenant environment where people might be sensitive about their data. Regarding the work in the Activity, I thought this would be encapsulated in the entity class itself so the work would only have to be done once. I was thinking of this when using a UUID, either 1) generating it when the class is instantiated (solving @NonNull issue) or 2) setting it prior to the insert.